# Skeuomorphic switch CSS3 sprite animation only works half the time

Tags: jquery, css-sprites, css-animations

My sprite animation works perfectly on the odd clicks (1, 3, 5 . .) which puts the switch in the down position, but I can't get the even clicks(2, 4, 6. . .) to fire the animation that puts the switch in the up position.  Cross browser CSS removed from the post but is in the Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/aNsHU/8/

**HTML**

```
<div class="switch s-up"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".switch").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("s-down s-up");
  });

})​
```

**CSS**

```
.switch{
  background: transparent url(http://i.imgur.com/taIR0.jpg);
  height:65px;
  width: 75px;
  margin-bottom:75px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.s-down{
  animation: play .4s steps(5);
}
.s-up{
  animation: reverse .4s steps(5);
}
.switch.s-down{
  background: transparent url(http://i.imgur.com/taIR0.jpg) -300px 0;
}


@keyframes play {
   0% { background-position:    0px; }
   100% { background-position: -375px; }
}

@keyframes reverse {
   0% { background-position:   -375px; }
   100% { background-position: 0px; }
}​
```

Comment: Why do you use a `div`? Why not use a `button` (or at least ARIA roles)? A `button` is made to be clicked, as are input type submit, image and button and links; a `div` isn't

Comment: Yes, I could use a button instead of a div, but your comment has no relevance to my question. Switching that out would not make the animation work differently.

Comment: I wasn't answering your question but commenting about your code. That's why I used the comment part under a SO question and not the "Your answer" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to the person that inspired the initial code to help me solve the problem.  The s-up class needs to contain both the play and reverse animations.  Thanks http://simurai.com/.

```
.s-up{
  animation: play reverse .4s steps(5);
}
```

The fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/hEfpt/